# When role assignment changes, authorization token still presents a user with the old roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I essentially have the setup described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martinkearn/archive/2015/03/25/securing-and-working-securely-with-web-api.aspx

The trouble is, if a user's roles are modified after receiving a token, the change is not reflected unless the user logs in again and receives a new token.

For example:

- user is in role "ABC"
- user logs in, receives a token
- user uses token to access endpoint decorated with [Authorize(Roles="ABC")] (as expected)
- administrator takes user out of role "ABC"
- **user can STILL use token to access endpoint decorated with [Authorize(Roles="ABC")]**  (unexpected)
- user discards token, logs in again, receives a new token
- user uses new token to access endpoint decorated with [Authorize(Roles="ABC")] and gets 401 (as expected)

In other words, unless the user requests a new token (logs in again), HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("ABC") returns true, even though the AspNetUserRoles table shows that user does NOT have that role.

How can I update (or perhaps invalidate?) the token when changes are made to the AspNetUserRoles table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token stores identity information (username, id) as well as all the roles that the user had when logging in. It does this so it doesn't have to hit the database for user info every time you need to check permissions, but it has the downside of not changing when roles information changes.

If you're okay with hitting the database every time, I would build a custom Authorize attribute by inheriting from AuthorizeAttribute and overriding the OnAuthorization method. If you don't want to hit the database on every role check, you could still populate a cache of when the roles were most recently changed and only hit the database if the roles update date for that user is later than the ticket date.

For example:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Redirect to login page
            filterContext.Result = Redirect("Login", "Index");
            return;
        }

        var roles = GetRolesFromDb();
        if (!Roles.Any(r => roles.Contains(r)))
            filterContext.Result = Redirect("Error", "AccessDenied");
    }

    private RedirectToRouteResult Redirect(string controller, string action, string area = "")
    {
        return new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
        {
            controller,
            action,
            area,
        });
    }
}
```