# Authorize attribute doesn't work when role is changed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity, asp.net-core-identity, authorize

I am using attribute `[Authorize]` to access endpoint.
For example

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, CustomerManager, CustomerUser, ClientManager, ClientUser")]
```

When the user's role is downgraded, if he uses the previous access token, he can log in under the role that has already been deleted.
I can solve it like this:

```cs
if (!await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(currentUser, Roles.Admin))
{
    return Forbid();
}
```

But is it possible to solve this with attribute [Authorize]?

I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679631/when-role-assignment-changes-authorization-token-still-presents-a-user-with-the) 8 years ago, but maybe something has already changed?

Comment: You would need to refresh the token. See if this helps: https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/05/30/refresh-tokens-in-asp-net-core-web-api/

Comment: You might have a look at [this blog](https://fusionauth.io/learn/expert-advice/tokens/revoking-jwts). The idea contains in it is that: the most common way is setting a short valid time duration, for example 5 minutes, then having a refresh token to do a refresh. If we want to avoid illegal operations during the 5 minutes, we have to create event trigger, that means when a user role downgraded happened in the server, server has to broadcast this event, and the client which signing this user should revoke the stored access token.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC, you need to log out the user whose role has been changed. If you use the API with JWT you need to make a new token.